# Why is my while function not working on Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm pretty new here and looking for some more programming knowledge. I'm sorry if this question is already answered or if it might be stupid.

I'm trying to build a simple programming game. But the while function is not letting me. I guess it's something really simple for you guys, so please help!

I want to create a looping game for guessing the right number.

I've tried looking on google for different codes but no luck so far.

```
#This is a guess the number game.
import random

print('Hello, what is your name?')
name = input()

print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

print('Take a guess......')
guess = int(input()

while guess != secretNumber:
    print('Take a guess.')


if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
```

The problem seems to be in the "while function", I want it to loop non stop until someone guesses the number.

Comment: You missed closing parenthesis after input()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a beginner as well! It's nice to have someone to learn together.

Here are what I think you are trying to do:

```
import random

print('Hello, what is your name?')
name = input()

print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

print('Take a guess......')
guess = int(input())
guessesTaken = 1

while guess != secretNumber:
    print('Take another guess.')
    guessesTaken += 1
    guess = int(input())

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
```

What I edited in there:

1) I added the right parenthesis on line #10;

2) On line #15 I add 1 to guessesTaken every time a guess is wrong to count how many attempts there have been;

3) On line #16 I ask for an input again after the previous guess is wrong, so that the player actually has a chance to reenter a different guess.

Like I said, I am new to python as well (first time posting here actually). But I hope this helps!

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much! Do you have discord or something? So we can stay in touch.

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking for another guess in the loop (there's not `input` in the loop), you should use an infinite `while` loop and `break` out of it when the guess is correct. You can also put the text you want to prompt inside the `input` function instead of printing it with `print`:

```
while True:
    guess = int(input('Take a guess: '))
    if guess == secretNumber:
        print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
        break
```